# "DeferCommit was set to false for this upload session" Error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to implement [Upload large files with an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session).

For now I have (getting the upload session):

```
UploadSession uploadSession = await graphClient
    .Users["user3@myComp.onmicrosoft.com"]
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath(@"\someFolder\file.txt")
    .CreateUploadSession()
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

The response from this request is some session URL but when I upload the file chunk to this URL I'm getting an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "DeferCommit was set to false for this upload session."
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Comment: Are you using the [production](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) or the [beta](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet) version of the SDK?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I have downloaded the latest version of `Microsoft.Graph` from NuGet, after some canges in my code the error repaced with: `{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"The Content-Range header is missing or malformed."}}`

Comment: `Content-Range` is used when you're uploading chunks, not when you are creating a session. Whatever is happening, your code sample doesn't show enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing how the request to upload the bytes was made I'm left to guess a little - but I believe the issue is that you used a `POST` instead of a `PUT`. The session URL returned needs to have `PUT` requests made to it, with appropriate `Content-Range` headers, in order to upload and commit the data.

Comment: That was the problem